# Aws Glue pypark UDF is throwing error An error occurred while calling o104.showString. Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue, pyspark

I need to get an expected dataframe in aws glue using pyspark showing at the end

```
    #################Initial Dataframe#################
    +---+--------------------+-------------------+
    |_c0|                 _c1|               time|
    +---+--------------------+-------------------+
    |  1|                null|2020-05-30 19:36:32|
    |  2|Mobii5              |2020-05-30 19:36:32|
    |  3|Nooft biHi ooFrame 2|2020-05-30 19:36:32|
    |  4|Samsung mobile   ...|2020-05-30 19:36:32|
    |  5|Samsung ppjomes  ...|2020-05-30 19:36:32|
    |  6| samsung GTP G Tv ne|2020-05-30 19:36:32|
    |  7| all mightyPanasoci |2020-05-30 19:36:32|
    |  8|Samsung hola       .|2020-05-30 19:36:32|
    |  9|Mooron phoines Mondo|2020-05-30 19:36:32|
    | 10|Samsung Guru .......|2020-05-30 19:36:32|
    +---+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Below is my code

```
    time_udf = udf(lambda x: year(x), IntegerType())

    timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                new_df = df.withColumn('time',unix_timestamp(lit(timestamp),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').cast("timestamp"))
                print(new_df.show(10))
                time.sleep(30)
    df1 = new_df.withColumn('Year',time_udf(col("time")))
    df1.createOrReplaceTempView("people")
                sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM people")
                sqlDF.show()
                print(df1.printSchema())
                return(df1)
```

Need to get an output like shown above using aws UDF pyspark

```
    ###############Expected###################
    +---+--------------------+-------------------+----+
    |_c0|                 _c1|               time|Year|
    +---+--------------------+-------------------+----+
    |  1|                null|2020-05-29 20:07:58|2020|
    |  2|Mobiistar Prime 5...|2020-05-29 20:07:58|2020|
    |  3|NTT Hikari i-Frame 2|2020-05-29 20:07:58|2020|
    |  4|Samsung SM-P605K ...|2020-05-29 20:07:58|2020|
    |  5|Samsung SM-G850W ...|2020-05-29 20:07:58|2020|
    |  6|samsung GTP G Tv ne |2020-05-29 20:07:58|2020|
    |  7|all mightyPanasoci  |2020-05-29 20:07:58|2020|
    |  8|Samsung hola       .|2020-05-29 20:07:58|2020|
    |  9|Mooron phoines Mondo|2020-05-29 20:07:58|2020|
    | 10|Samsung Guru .......|2020-05-29 20:07:58|2020|
    +---+--------------------+-------------------+----+
```

I can get it right using this below line

```
    df1 = new_df.withColumn('Year',year(new_df.time))
```

But i need to use UDF as requirments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `year` inside UDF, as it is pyspark function.

If you really need to use UDF, you can do it with usual python datetime functions:

```
from datetime import datetime

def extractYear(datestring):
   dt = datetime.strptime(datestring, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
   return dt.year

time_udf = udf(lambda x: extractYear(x), IntegerType())
```

But using `year`, like in `.withColumn('Year',year(new_df.time))` would be just easier and quicker, so if it works - better stick to it.

Comment: hey there!  AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`2012`' given input columns: [_c0, _c1];;\n'Project [_c0#10, _c1#11, <lambda>('2012) AS Year#31]\n+- Relation[_c0#10,_c1#11] csv\n"

Comment: I know i've yused the same process too before but didn't work out in glue well i don't know wheter i'm doing it right way or wrong